# C# Null Static Analysis False Negative?

Tags: c#, .net, nullable-reference-types

I am working in a project with nullable annotation context enabled, but we have a dependency on a library with nullable annotation context disabled.

Simplified example of the static analysis behavior I'm seeing in our project:

```
class Something
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Foo foo = new();
        Console.WriteLine("foo.Bar: " + foo.Bar); // Null static analysis claim: 'Bar' is not null here. Runtime behavior: 'Bar' is null
    }
}

#nullable disable
class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

My question is: is this static analysis behavior expected? It would be great to be able to rely on the null static analysis features to reason about our code & omit unnecessary null checks, but this is giving me doubts.

Comment: This is like telling the inspector when you go through security check that there are no suspicious items in my bag.

Comment: Well yeah, you disabled null-analysis, so C# doesn't do it. How is this unexpected?

Comment: @Sweeper I would expect the static analyzer to not assert that a property "is not null here" when it actually can be null (as in the example). It would be better for the static analyzer to make no assertion around null state of a property than an incorrect one.

Comment: In case it wasn't clear from the example the `Something` class above has null-analysis enabled while `Foo` class has it disabled.

Comment: From [this discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/42318), it seems like this behaviour is by-design.

Comment: If you don't mind considerable effort, you could write an Analyzer that explicitly _does_ analysis for members of that assembly.

Comment: @Sweeper thanks for the info. That link and the [discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/2244) linked from it helped me get a better understanding on the issue here. If you aren't familiar with all the nuances of the null state analyzer, blanket statements like '"Bar" is not null here' can lead to incorrect coding practices (e.g. choosing to omit a null check when it may still be warranted). Something as simple as altering that language would go a long way toward helping folks avoid gaining a false sense of security that a variable is not null when it very well may be!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is by design. When you have a code compiled with NRT disabled you will get nullable-oblivious state. From [Nullable contexts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references#nullable-contexts) section of the docs:

> The nullable annotation context determines the compiler's behavior. There are four values for the nullable annotation context:

> - `disable`: The code is nullable-oblivious. Disable matches the behavior before nullable reference types were enabled, except the new syntax produces warnings instead of errors.

From the [Nullable reference types (NRTs) docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references#nullable-contexts):

> Reference type variables in code compiled in a disabled context are nullable-oblivious. ... However, **the default state of a nullable-oblivious variable is not-null**.

And from [Understand contexts and warnings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-migration-strategies#understand-contexts-and-warnings):

> Each variable has a default nullable state that depends on its nullability:
>
> - Nullable variables have a default `null-state` of `maybe-null`.
> - Non-nullable variables have a default `null-state` of `not-null`.
> - **Nullable oblivious variables have a default `null-state` of `not-null`**.

Comment: Thanks for the context here. What an odd choice: "Nullable oblivious variables have a default null-state of not-null." Would it not make more sense to have nullable oblivious variables have some unknown null state? Having the tools explicitly tell me a variable is not null when it can be is super misleading. A statement like "Unable to determine null state of 'Bar'" would be more correct and informative IMO.

Comment: And I wouldn't suggest that warnings be created for every null oblivious variable -- that variable hover over text in VS could just do a lot more to steer people the right direction.

Comment: @Simea was glad to help! It is hard to tell why design team has made such decision, but we have to work with what we have. Personal opinion - it would be great if null-oblivious variable would have configurable null state (via compiler flag/project setting) but maybe it was too costly to implement.